# Draw a rectangle of a specific size

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I draw a rectangle of a specific size?  I need to draw one that is 1072 pixels wide and 620 pixels tall.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Select `rectangle tool` and go to the rectangle  option there you can put fixed size from drop down.

[image]

another thing is you can create same marquee selection with fixed height and width see attached pics.

[image]

hope this will help and images say's more than words.

Comment: This method also works in CS6. The icon is different (it's a little gear wheel in the control bar).

Comment: wow anyone know what version started this? I can't believe I never knew this one.

Comment: I guess with Creative suites

Comment: In CS2, which I'm still using, the Rectangle tool has no way of specifying size. You'd have to watch the Info palette's W and H values as you draw it. You can specify a fixed size for a Marquee/Selection as above though.

Comment: so we can say after cs2..:D

Answer (score 11):

In Photoshop CS6, simply click on the canvas with the Rectangle tool selected, them enter the width and height.

[image: Create Rectangle]

In versions prior to Photoshop CS6, you can set the size in the shape options, before to drawing the shape itself (please see the other answer on this page for screenshots and more info). This also works in Photoshop CS6, but a single click on the canvas is easier, if you have CS6.

You can also draw the shape while watching the info panel, and/or adjust afterwards by nudging (make sure you have pixel snapping turned on, so you're adjusting in whole pixel increments).

Comment: Why the negative vote? The advice is correct and detailed.

Comment: No idea. I upvoted and also added an alternative method to doing it on older versions of photoshop without having to try and make a precise drag using the navigator.

Comment: I would just like to add that this works in Illustrator as well and it wouldn't surprise me if it worked in other Adobe products as well.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks. Is it possible to adjust using the options bar in versions prior to CS6 (For rectangles only)? Been a while since I used CS5.

Comment: In versions prior to Photoshop CS6, you have to draw the shape while watching the info panel and/or adjust the size after drawing.  Who said that :o

Comment: Hey, good to see you here, Marc!

Comment: @Pankaj Good point. I forgot about that one. I've edited the answer to reflect it.